Compare between 2 different dates via powershell
I want to compare cutoffDate and LogonDate variables. I am using a function called Get-LastLogon. But it's not working properly.
PS C:\Windows\system32> $LogonDate
Monday, December 11, 2023 11:54:34 PM

PS C:\Windows\system32> $cutoffDate

Friday, June 7, 2024 10:33:45 AM

Script:
# Define the date 90 days ago from today
$cutoffDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)

$LogonDate = (Get-LastLogon -Identity "user").DateTime

if ($LogonDate -lt $cutoffDate) {

#Do something
write-host "ok"

}


But it's not working properly. Can you please elaborate?

Let's say, if $LogonDate is less than $cutoffDate, I want to run some commands inside the if statement. when I run the above command it doesn't give any result. Normally I expect write-host “ok” output.

What is Get-LastLogon? Do you have link to the Cmdlet docs?

Get-LastLogon is custom powershell function. I have no problem with the function here. I want to compare every 2 dates above here. I wrote the sample outputs.

Can you print the type of both variables using GetType()?

$LogonDate is a probably of type [String], where $cutoffDate is of type [DateTime] (check: $LogonDate.GetType()). Generally in a comparison, the left-hand-side dictates the type casting, meaning that you comparing the dates as string objects (rather than datetime objects). In other words: if you swap the operands (and negate the operator): (if ($cutoffDate -ge $LogonDate) {...), it should work as expected.

$cutoffDate.GetType() -> DateTime
$LogonDate.GetType()  -> String

Please add the information of your last comment to the question

Without the code to get-lastlogon, the question doesn't make sense.

From the comments in the question, it appears that:
$LogonDate  = [String]'Monday, December 11, 2023 11:54:34 PM'
$cutoffDate = [DateTime]'Friday, June 7, 2024 10:33:45 AM'

$LogonDate.GetType().Name
String

$cutoffDate.GetType().Name
DateTime


In PowerShell (as in most other loosely programming languages), the operand at the LHS (left hand side) of the operator, dictates the type casting used to align the operands types before executing the operation.

This applies to most operators.

Not only to arithmetic operators:

'1' + 2
12

1 + '2'
3


But also to comparison operators

Which means that if the string type ($LogonDate) is at the LHS, you will do a string compare:
$LogonDate -lt $cutoffDate
False

Note here that even Monday, December 11, 2023 11:54:34 PM comes before Friday, June 7, 2024 10:33:45 AM, the comparison is False because the M in Monday isn't less than the F in Fryday.
In other words, the solution to your issue is to swap the operands and negate the operator (the opposite of the -lt operator is: -ge) so that the DateTime type ($cutoffDate) is at the LHS and consequently a DateTime compare is preformed:
$cutoffDate -ge $LogoDate
True

For more details, see the (as of today) updated about comparison operators document.

The other option is convert the string value to a DateTime value for your comparison, or all of your date values if you don't want to keep track of what type each of them are. So for instance either
if ($(Get-Date -Date $LogonDate) -lt $cutoffDate) {
or
if ($(Get-Date -Date $LogonDate) -lt $(Get-Date -Date $cutoffDate)) {
